# Complex Analytic Function's Power Series

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series, holomorphic-functions

Studying complex function, I'm facing some fundamental question:
Given open and bounded set $\Omega \in \mathbb{C}$ and $f:\Omega \rightarrow \Omega$ holomorphic on $\Omega$ which $f(z_{0})=z_{0}$. $f$ can be represented as power series around $z_{0}$ as $f(z)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_{n}(z-z_{0})^{n}$ so within the radius of convergence around $z_{0}$ the equality holds. therefore when I plug in $z_{0}$ I get $f(z_{0})= \sum _{n=1} ^{\infty}a_{n}(z_{0}-z_{0})^{n}=0$ so $z_{0}=0$. On the other hand, I can create the function $g(z)=z$ which is also holomorphic on $\Omega$ but for $0\neq z_{1}\in \Omega$ I also get that $z_{1}=0$ which contradicts with the definition of $f$. What am I missing?

Comment: If $f(z_0) = z_0$ then $f(z) = z_0 + \sum_{i=1}^{\infty}a_{n}(z-z_{0})^{n}$ and plugging in $z_0$ gives just $z_0 = z_0$. Your conclusion $z_0 = 0$ seems to be wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing the first term in the sum

$$
f(z) = \sum_{\color{red}{n = 0}}^{+\infty}a_n(z - z_0)^n
$$

with this in mind

$$
f(z_0) = a_0 + a_1(z_0 - z_0) + \cdots = a_0
$$

In you case case $a_0 = z_0$